# How to get an new instance of a bean in a Argonaut controller method

Tags: argonaut

I understand that controller in Argonaut are singletone(*), therefore I do not want to havea bean instance injected with a bean to be used in the controller methods. I want instead to get a new instance of a bean. For example:

```
@Controller("/store")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
public class StoreController {
  @Post("/get") @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Chunk> get(@Body Set<String> ids) {
    Store store ... <- injected 
  }
}
```

Is it possible at all in Argonaut?